# What is the best approach to use remote reindexing API of elasticcluster when migration millions of documents?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, system-design, reindex

I have approx. 100million documents in an index and i want to migrate it to new cluster using reindex API. I want to do it in the throttling manner.

I tried using **request_per_seconds** to *100000* but it will take hours to complete whole process.
Q.1 Can i use **request_per_seconds** to maybe *1000000* to reduce process time?
Q.2 Is there any better approach i can use for better reindexing in throttling manner?

Answer (score 0):

Reindex supports Sliced scroll to parallelize the reindexing process. This parallelization can improve efficiency and provide a convenient way to break the request down into smaller parts.

```
POST _reindex?slices=5&refresh
{
  "source": {
    "index": "my-index-000001"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "my-new-index-000001"
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#docs-reindex-automatic-slice

You can also read about the advice for optimizing for speed, things like:

- Disabling refresh for that period
- Reduce replicas to 0
  etc..

Link:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-indexing-speed.html